# VBScript how to read any files that begins with testdata_.txt?

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I have a system that auto-generate testdata_1.txt, testdata_2.txt and so on. I wish to read the file that begins with testdata_ and process it, how do I go about this? I have tried using testdata_* but in the following code but it doesn't work. Any help is appreaciated. Thank you very much.

```
    sPath = "database/"
    sFile = "testdata_*.txt"
    sFileName = sPath & sFile    
    Set fso = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
    set fs = fso.OpenTextFile(Server.MapPath(sFileName), 1, true) 
    if not fs.AtEndOfStream then
        Do while not fs.AtEndOfStream
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can help you:

```
sPath = "database/"
sFile = "testdata_"

'Modify this line to indicate the disk drive where the files are located.
sDir = "C:\" & sPath

Set obj_FS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set obj_FolderBase = obj_FS.GetFolder(sDir)

For Each obj_File In obj_FolderBase.Files    
    If Mid(obj_File.Name,1,9) = sFile then      
        set objReadFile = obj_FS.OpenTextFile (obj_File.Name, 1, False) 
        content = objReadFile.ReadAll 
        objReadFile.close 
        Wscript.Echo content           
    End If       
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the folder choosing which files you want. I use `Left()` here.

```
'On Error Resume Next
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dirname = InputBox("Enter Dir name")
    Set fldr = fso.GetFolder(Dirname)

    Set Fls = fldr.files
    On Error Resume Next

    For Each thing in Fls
         If Left(thing.name,9) = "TestData_" then 
              msgbox thing.name
         End If
    Next
```